# MYSQL InnoDB engine indexing (B-Tree), and one-to-one relationship

Tags: mysql, database

Briefly, I know that Indexes are best used on columns that are frequently used in where clauses, and in any kind of sorting, such as "order by", and also with high cardinality cols. on the other side, however if overdone, indexes slow down write operations and also take much space on disk.

I have a user registration table with the following fields:

```
          ID INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          User_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
          BirthDay DATE NOT NULL,
          password CHAR(70) NOT NULL,  
          Security_hint VARCHAR(27) NOT NULL,
          Email VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
          userType ENUM ('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
          Signup_Date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          activation   TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          Ip BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (ID),
          UNIQUE KEY User_name (User_name,Email)
```

1. I am very convinced with the datatypes I have chosen for all the fields.
2. the fields `Signup_Date` and `Security_hint` will rarely be queried against, so I decided to isolate them in a separate table and use 1-1 relationship using foreign keys. is this strategy efficient? is there any performance hit that might be resulted from this strategy?
3. IMPORTANT ONE: Do I have to index the PASSWORD field as well so as to make the log in process very fast??

Thank you very much guys in advance.

EDIT: my login query is `SELECT columns FROM users WHERE username = "x" AND password = "stuff"`. I am using index on email just to make the checking of an existing email fast, as emails and user names must be unique for every user

Comment: You should only ask one question as it makes it easier to answer. By answering two questions at once it could be you answer the first answer perfectly and someone else has the best answer to the second question -> which one of the should be accepted?

Comment: @Philipp. if the two questions are answered that would be great, if only one that has to be answered I would like it to be the IMPORTANT ONE. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD 1: Email is usually defined as VARCHAR(255), not 225. You store password as CHAR(70) - I suppose you use some hash that returns EXACTLY 70 bytes, otherwise you should use VARCHAR.

AD 2: 1-to-1 relations perform poorly in general as you have to run JOINs. The only situation I would consider separating data with a 1-to-1 relation is when one part of the original table gets written HEAVILY. In this case you separate this part so that you do not have to rebuild indexes on other columns all the time.

AD 3: I suppose you use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username = "myname" AND password = sha256("mypass") AND activation = 1
```

In that case all searched columns have to be indexed: `username, password, activation`.

AD unique key: `UNIQUE KEY User_name (User_name,Email)` means you can have more users with same user_name and different emails, and vice versa. You should use 2 separate unique keys to make all user_names AND emails unique.

Answer (score 1):

> the fields Signup_Date and Security_hint will rarely be queried against, so I decided to isolate them in a separate table and use 1-1 relationship using foreign keys. is this strategy efficient? is there any performance hit that might be resulted from this strategy?

I see no value in handling it this way. If it doesn't affect the size of your table in a critical way you are only adding the need for unnecessary joins.

> IMPORTANT ONE: Do I have to index the PASSWORD field as well so as to make the log in process very fast??

Depends on your login.

If you are using something like:

```
SELECT columns FROM users WHERE username = "x" AND email ="y" AND password = "stuff"
```

You will be fine, as the `index` and `unique-constraint` of `username` + `email` take care of finding the user by `index` usage.

If you are only checking for username and password in your login, an index on (username, password) could make sense **IF** you think there will be **A LOT** of users with the same username. Otherwise it will use the index for the username and will ususally be fast too.

Comment: Yeah, my last paragraph handles that scenario. You don't need another index for the login